# Использование свойства потока IsAlive

Tags: c#

Разбирая тему многопоточности по Шиелду 4.0, столкнулся с проблемой. В книге описано, что свойство IsAlive возвращает true если поток, на котором он вызывается, активен. Пишу следующий код:

```
class MyThread
{
    public int Count;
    public Thread thr2;

    public MyThread(string name)
    {
        Count = 0;
        thr2 = new Thread(this.Run);
        thr2.Name = name;
        thr2.Start();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{thr2.Name} начат");
        for (int counter = Count; counter < 10; counter++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            Console.WriteLine($"В потоке {thr2.Name} Count = {Count}");
            Count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"{thr2.Name} завершен.");
    }
}
```

И точка входа в программу:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Основной поток начат");

        MyThread first = new MyThread("Vasya");

        Thread newThrd = new Thread(first.Run);

        do
        {
            Console.Write(".");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
        } while (first.Count < 10);

        Console.WriteLine("Основной поток завершен.");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

По замыслу, если в цикле while-do в классе Program вместо first.Count < 10 написать newThrd.IsAlive, то результат выполнения программы не должен измениться. Однако на деле, при выполнении программы, основной поток может завершится сразу же после того, как будет создан другой поток. С помощью отладки иду по коду, и вижу, что свойство IsAvive принимает значение false, даже если другой поток не закончил свое выполнение. Почему так происходит, и как правильно написать программу используя свойство IsAlive?

Comment: А можно пример с IsAlive? Вы, надеюсь, не у newThrd проверяете это свойство, а у потока внутри вашего класса?

Comment: John, все верно, проверял не у потока, который я создал. Исправил, все работает так как должно.

Answer (score 0):

осознал ошибку, необходимо вызывать свойство на объекте именно мною созданного класса. Так:

```
do
{
  Console.Write(".");
  Thread.Sleep(100);
} while (first.thr2.IsAlive);
```

Я же вызвал на объекте потока, который никакого отношения к программе не имеет.